# Windows Cluster - Moving a node to different network

Tags: failovercluster, windows-cluster

I have a 3 node SQL always on cluster running , is it possible to move a node to different network(subnet) without evicting & creating the node again.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly network do you want to change? Heartbeat? Management? Also for sure you will have downtime. You can do it with this scenario: 
1. -> Go to the node that you want and stop cluster service 
2. -> go to Failover cluster and stop cluster network 
3. -> Change the subnet that you want 
4. -> do again present of the node to the cluster 
You can see this guidelines too: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/28165ecd-22e8-463d-95e3-bc10dd843f20/moving-the-cluster-to-another-network-segment

Anyway because it's an SQL Cluster and above i gave you guidelines that i have done in Hyper-V clusters i don't know if they have the same process about, and if everything works well. Don't forget that you will have definitely downtime.

Comment: currently 3 nodes are running 192.168.100.X network , we are creating a DR site with network 192.168.200.X , we want to move a node from 100.X to 200.X , so there 2 nodes will be in 100.X and one node in 200.X , all the nodes are VMs. What we need is to move one node VM from a host in 100.X to another host in DR site 200.X without evicting and adding the node again.

Comment: This is as i told you before. For hyper-v cluster the process is upper in my answer. About sql cluster i don't what will be the response of the cluster. Also as i said you will have downtime.